# AdMob address verification PIN - wrong letter?

Tags: android, admob, adsense, verification

I've received a letter from Google today. It should contain PIN which verifies my address, so I could pay out money I've earned from ads on my Android app. Instead it is a business verification code for some company - or at least what I think it is. It says *Google My Business* on the inside and has 5-letter code as well as these 3 steps:

1. Visit *google.com/verifymybusiness*
2. Sign in to your Google account.
3. Enter your verification code and submit!

I've typed once already this verification code on AdMob site, but it said it's incorrect. After 3 failed verifications the ads will be suspended, so I just want to be sure - **if that could really be the Google mistake and I should just wait for "Ask for new address verification PIN" link to unlock on AdMob site?** I've sent them an email as well, but I don't even know if the address was correct, because it was so hard to find and it was through some help form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, which is 3 days after I received first letter (with wrong informations), I got second letter from Google - now, with Google AdSense PIN, which **correctly confirmed** my address!

My guess is to be patient. ;)